# Is GPLv3-only compatible with GPLv3+?

Tags: gpl, license-compatibility, gpl-3

Suppose I'm working on a GPLv3-only project, and find some code licensed as GPL3+. Can I incorporate that code freely in my software without changing my license? If a hypothetical GPL v4 is released, does that mean that my program is suddenly both GPL v3 and GPL v4 compatible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual text of a GPLv3+ grant is

> This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License...; either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version

The option is *yours* as the redistributor. The "either" language means that you may opt to distribute the work under the GPLv3 only.

The virtually identical case of GPLv2+ code into GPLv2-only project is marked OK [the GPL compatibility matrix](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#AllCompatibility), with the annotation:

> You must follow the terms of GPLv2 when incorporating the code in this case. You cannot take advantage of terms in later versions of the GPL.

Comment: I didn't see any listing for GPL v3 only, so I wasn't sure if there was any difference. I was actually starting to doubt whether there was even any such thing as a v3-only option.